# Some function does not work because of different jQuery files

Tags: javascript, jquery, slider, horizontal-scrolling, parallax

I am working on a website that I use different jQuery files for different functions.
Such as light box, scrolling page horizontally.  these to functions work perfectly togeter.  But I added a new plugin which is parallax image.  And in a part of the plugin I have to add the following script in the body or head tag. So as soon as I add that, the parallax image works but the horizontal scroll stops.

here is the scripts:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

   $(window).load(function() {
      $.noConflict(); 
       jQuery('#world').fhparallax({
         editor:'off',
         automatic:0,
         mobile_auto_start:"yes",
         path:'parallax/js/ZeroClipboard.swf'
      }) 
   });
</script>
```

And these are the files related to horizontal scrolling:

```
  <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.scripts.js">
</script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="style/js/jquery.nivo.slider.js">
</script>
```

As I am using the [Nvio slider](http://nivo.dev7studios.com/demos/) so I think you know about the top links, but if you require I can give the the actual links of these js files.

Anyway I as I tested, everything is about (function() b/c when I changed it, in the top scripts the slider worked.

So is it possible to have both of these tools at the same page? If so, can you guide me to fix it please?
Thanks

Comment: I would suggest removing the line: `$.noConflict(); `.  That is not needed here and may be causing your other code to stop working.